# How to test validity of predict() function in R?

Tags: predictive-models

I am working on a dataset for linear regression in R.  After building the model (with the `lm()`function), I want to test my model on a new data point using the `predict()` function with a certain confidence interval. Is there a mechanism to verify whether predicting at this new data point is valid or not?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What would it mean for the new data point to be valid or invalid?

Comment: Confidence intervals don't answer your question: you want a *prediction interval.*  The new data point is consistent with the original model when it lies within that prediction interval.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16493.

Comment: You must do relatively stupid things to invalidate `predict.lm()`.

Answer (score 5):

> I am working on a dataset for linear regression in R. After building the model (with the lm()function), I want to test my model on a new data point using the predict() function with a certain confidence interval. Is there a mechanism to verify whether predicting at this new data point is valid or not?

It is not clear what you mean by

> using the predict() function with a certain confidence interval.

the `predict` function does not use a confidence interval. It uses the estimates from the fitted model to determine the value(s) of the response variable when the explanatory variable(s) take values provided (with the `newdata` parameter).

```
set.seed(15)
N <- 10

X1 <- rnorm(N,0,1)
X2 <- rnorm(N,0,2)
Y <- 10 + 2*X1 + 3*X2 + rnorm(N,0,1)

dt <- data.frame(Y, X1, X2)

m0 <- lm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = dt)

summary(m0)
```

Here we fit the model and obtain these results:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  10.4936     0.2589  40.524 1.45e-09 ***
X1            2.0075     0.2792   7.191 0.000179 ***
X2            3.1711     0.1614  19.653 2.21e-07 ***
```

The equation for the fitted model is therefore:

```
10.4936 + 2.0075*X1 + 3.1711*X2
```

So if we were to set X1=2 and X2=3 we would have

```
10.4936 + 2.0075*2 + 3.1711*3
```

which equals 24.0219. Now if we want to

> verify whether predicting at this new data point is valid or not?

We can do so like this:

```
predict(m0, newdata = data.frame(X1 = 2, X2 = 3))
```

which returns 24.02195 which matches the calculation we did manually, therefore verifying that the `predict` function worked correctly.

---

Edit: After clarification in the comments to this answer:

> I meant to ask of performance measures to conclude if 'predict()' is doing the correct thing. Like how the linear regression function 'lm()' has performance measures to quantify its behavior. Does my question make sense?

Unfortunately I still don't understand what you are asking. You say you want:

> performance measures to conclude if 'predict()' is doing the correct thing.

Well `predict` only has one job - to output a predicted value for the response or a confidence (or prediction) interval. I have demonstrated above that it is "doing the correct thing."

Then you ask about whether

> 'lm()' has performance measures to quantify its behavior

Unfortunately I don't know what you mean by this. If you are asking about the performance of `lm` itself, well most of the computation is done in compiled code written in C or Fortran for performance reasons. Further details are here:

[Least Squares Regression Step-By-Step Linear Algebra Computation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154485/least-squares-regression-step-by-step-linear-algebra-computation)

If you are asking about the performance of `predict` or something else, please clarify your question.

Comment: I don't get the feeling that the function doing the right calculation is in question.

Comment: @Dave I hear you. Hopefully my answer will prompt the OP to tell us what they mean by "test the validity"

Comment: `predict.lm()` has an option to return also interval estimates.

Comment: @MichaelM I was being deliberately obtuse, hoping to elicit more details from the OP about what they are asking :)

Comment: I also haven't understood it :-)

Comment: I meant to ask of performance measures to conclude if 'predict()' is doing the correct thing.  Like how the linear regression function 'lm()' has performance measures to quantify its behavior.  Does my question make sense?

Comment: @Nanda Please clarify that as an edit to your original question. If you could expand on what you see as measures of performance in the `lm` function, that would be helpful.