# Why $(y-Xb)^T(y-Xb)\ne y^Ty-b^TX^Ty$, where $b=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ is the least squares estimate?

Tags: least-squares

Let $b=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ be the ordinary least squares estimate. Then the sum of squared residuals is

$$\begin{align}
(y-Xb)^T(y-Xb)&=y^Ty-y^TXb-b^TX^Ty+b^TX^TXb\\
&=y^Ty-b^TX^Ty.
\end{align}$$

The `carbohydrate` data below is from the book [An Introduction to Generalized Linear Models (Fourth Edition)](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=AS_3DwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=An+Introduction+to+Generalized+Linear+Models+Fourth+Edition&ots=JbfxDk66Pf&sig=-GyaKQxljkvm7IStB4v8x8dBtQg#v=onepage&q=An%20Introduction%20to%20Generalized%20Linear%20Models%20Fourth%20Edition&f=false)
[image]

```r
carbohydrate <- structure(list(carbohydrate = c(33, 40, 37, 27, 30, 43, 34, 48, 
30, 38, 50, 51, 30, 36, 41, 42, 46, 24, 35, 37), age = c(33, 
47, 49, 35, 46, 52, 62, 23, 32, 42, 31, 61, 63, 40, 50, 64, 56, 
61, 48, 28), weight = c(100, 92, 135, 144, 140, 101, 95, 101, 
98, 105, 108, 85, 130, 127, 109, 107, 117, 100, 118, 102), protein = c(14, 
15, 18, 12, 15, 15, 14, 17, 15, 14, 17, 19, 19, 20, 15, 16, 18, 
13, 18, 14)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))

N=dim(carbohydrate)[1]
X <- carbohydrate
X[,1] <- rep(1, N)
y <- as.matrix(carbohydrate$carbohydrate)
#b=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty
X <- as.matrix(X)
XTX <- t(X) %*% X
XTy <- t(X) %*% y
XTX_inv <- matlib::inv(XTX)
b=XTX_inv %*% XTy

#Residual S
t(y - X %*% b) %*% (y - X %*% b)
#Residual S
t(y) %*% y - 2*(t(y) %*% X %*% b) + t(b) %*% XTX %*% b
#Residual S
t(y) %*% y - t(b) %*% XTy
```

```r
        [,1]
[1,] 567.6806
         [,1]
[1,] 567.6806
      [,1]
[1,] 545.8
```

Why is $(y-Xb)^T(y-Xb)\ne y^Ty-b^TX^Ty$?

It seems the manually calculated coefficients are not correct, the `coefficients` from the `lm` function can match:

```r
res.lm=lm(carbohydrate~age+weight+protein,data=carbohydrate)
b2 <- res.lm$coefficients
#Residual S
t(y - X %*% b2) %*% (y - X %*% b2)
#Residual S
t(y) %*% y - 2*(t(y) %*% X %*% b2) + t(b2) %*% XTX %*% b2
#Residual
t(y) %*% y - t(b2) %*% XTy
```

```r
[,1]
[1,] 567.6629
         [,1]
[1,] 567.6629
         [,1]
[1,] 567.6629
```

Comment: "[T]hen the residual is"--no, that's the sum of squared residuals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem can be traced back to numerical issues in the calculation of `XTX_inv` via `matlib::inv`:

```r
matlib::inv(XTX) %*% XTX
#      carbohydrate         age      weight     protein
# [1,]   0.99999309 -0.00031792 -0.00078345 -0.00010996
# [2,]  -0.00000260  0.99988772 -0.00030058 -0.00004118
# [3,]   0.00000747  0.00033684  1.00084915  0.00011914
# [4,]   0.00000563  0.00026482  0.00063345  1.00008974
```

You can do better by using `base::solve`:

```r
solve(XTX) %*% XTX
#              carbohydrate           age        weight       protein
# carbohydrate 1.000000e+00 -2.046363e-12 -3.637979e-12 -5.684342e-13
# age          5.551115e-17  1.000000e+00  1.421085e-14  8.881784e-16
# weight       1.387779e-17  1.776357e-15  1.000000e+00  6.661338e-16
# protein      0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00
```

Replacing `matlib::inv(XTX)` by `solve(XTX)` in your code solves the apparent inconsistency.

Note, however, that `stats::lm` computes `b2` by using a QR decomposition of `X`, which is more numerically stable:

```r
b3 <- qr.coef(qr(X), y)
all.equal(b2, b3)
# [1] TRUE

b
#            [,1]
# [1,] 36.9598000
# [2,] -0.1137718
# [3,] -0.2277399
# [4,]  1.9579218

b2
#                    [,1]
# carbohydrate 36.9600559
# age          -0.1136764
# weight       -0.2280174
# protein       1.9577126
```

---

**Addendum** (2024-01-14)

Both `matlib::inv` and `base::solve` ultimatly use [Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting](https://www.statlect.com/matrix-algebra/Gaussian-elimination#hid6) to calculate the inverse of a matrix.
`matlib::inv` does this by calling `matlib::Inverse` which in turn calls `matlib::gaussianElimination`. While the latter provides a reasonable implementation for didactic purposes, `base::solve` leverages the superior [LAPACK subroutine `dgesv`](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d8/da6/group__gesv_ga831ce6a40e7fd16295752d18aed2d541.html#ga831ce6a40e7fd16295752d18aed2d541) for its computations. 
That being said, if the tolerance argument `tol` of `matlib::Inverse`, used to check for zero pivots, is set to `.Machine$double.eps`, we get a better inverse:

```r
matlib::Inverse(XTX, tol = .Machine$double.eps) %*% XTX
#       carbohydrate          age        weight       protein
# [1,]  1.000000e+00 1.136868e-12  4.547474e-12  2.273737e-13
# [2,] -2.386980e-15 1.000000e+00 -2.096101e-13 -3.863576e-14
# [3,]  1.115913e-13 5.175860e-12  1.000000e+00  1.780798e-12
# [4,]  6.261658e-14 2.927436e-12  7.105427e-12  1.000000e+00
```

Instead of solving the normal equations $X^\top X b = X^\top y$ directly (e.g., via Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting) to calculate the OLSE $b$, `stats::lm` uses a QR decomposition of $X$. Some details are given in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/154514).
This avoids calculations with the matrix cross-product $X^\top X$, whose [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices) squares the one of the (potentially ill-conditioned) design matrix $X$. Another advantage of `stats::lm`'s (more precisely, [`dqrdc2`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/appl/dqrdc2.f)'s) [QR decomposition with column pivoting](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node42.html) is that it also works with rank-deficient (design) matrices.

Comment: I would actually say that in most cases  we shouldn't invert a matrix at all. We want to solve a system. So more like `solve(crossprod(X), crossprod(X,y))` to be proper about this.

Comment: @usεr11852 Agreed. And `qr.coef(qr(X), y)` does solve a (simplified) system of linear equations, but without computing the matrix cross-product $X^\top X$, which can itself be numerically unstable. I'll expand on that later when I find some time. Compared to your suggestion this is slower but can also detect linearly dependent columns in the design matrix.

Comment: Cool, it was more to keep it close to the $(X^TX)^{-1} X^Ty$ wording.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that if you use `XTX_inv <- solve(XTX)` the results are identical. So, the inverse of `XTX` obtained by `matlib::inv()` is less precise.

Answer (score 1):

*matlib: A collection of matrix functions for teaching and learning*

Use solve instead.

```
carbohydrate <- structure(list(carbohydrate = c(33, 40, 37, 27, 30, 43, 34, 48, 
30, 38, 50, 51, 30, 36, 41, 42, 46, 24, 35, 37), age = c(33, 
47, 49, 35, 46, 52, 62, 23, 32, 42, 31, 61, 63, 40, 50, 64, 56, 
61, 48, 28), weight = c(100, 92, 135, 144, 140, 101, 95, 101, 
98, 105, 108, 85, 130, 127, 109, 107, 117, 100, 118, 102), protein = c(14, 
15, 18, 12, 15, 15, 14, 17, 15, 14, 17, 19, 19, 20, 15, 16, 18, 
13, 18, 14)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))

N=dim(carbohydrate)[1]
X <- carbohydrate
X[,1] <- rep(1, N)
y <- as.matrix(carbohydrate$carbohydrate)
#b=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty
X <- as.matrix(X)
XTX <- t(X) %*% X
XTy <- t(X) %*% y
#XTX_inv <- matlib::inv(XTX)
XTX_inv <- solve(XTX)
b=XTX_inv %*% XTy

#Residual S
t(y - X %*% b) %*% (y - X %*% b)
#Residual S
t(y) %*% y - 2*(t(y) %*% X %*% b) + t(b) %*% XTX %*% b
#Residual S
t(y) %*% y - t(b) %*% XTy
```

````
         [,1]
[1,] 567.6629
         [,1]
[1,] 567.6629
         [,1]
[1,] 567.6629
```
````

Comment: Perhaps you could expand your answer to articulate what causes the loss of precision and how this function mitigates this